# spl-token getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo

Tags: spl-token

spl-token getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo This method always takes a long time to execute, and may eventually throw an exception getAccountError

```
 const token = new Token(conn, NATIVE_MINT, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, owner)
        //use payer to pay fee to create ast account of vs if not exist
        const vsTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(token, vsASTOwner, owner, conn)

        const solTransferAccount = Keypair.fromSecretKey(stringToUint8Array(sysInfo.solanaKey['solTransferAccount']))
        //find from ast account
        const receiverTokenAccount = await token.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(solTransferAccount.publicKey);
```

Comment: Is there an actual error that comes with this?

Comment: this is error message: \n
Error: Failed to find account

Comment: transaction.add(Token.createCloseAccountInstruction(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, receiverTokenAccount.address, solTransferAccount.publicKey, solTransferAccount.publicKey, []))

Is it because this code is executed?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo created an account when there isn't one yet. When mainnet is congested it may take a while to get the transaction through.

Looks like you are on an old version of SPL-token.
Try update to

```
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.1"
```

and use `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` instead.

If problems persist you may want to use the internal function in case the token account does not exist yet.

```
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
                    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                        payer.publicKey,
                        associatedToken,
                        owner,
                        mint,
                        programId,
                        associatedTokenProgramId
                    )
                );
```

and add priority fees to it.

That would look somewhat like this:

```
const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
  units: 2000,
});

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
  microLamports: 20000,
});

const transaction = new Transaction()
  .add(modifyComputeUnits)
  .add(addPriorityFee)
  .add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toAccount,
      lamports: 10000000,
    }),
  );
```

Here is a guide on that topic:
https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/how-to-use-priority-fees